# inheriting uigesturerecognizer iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, inheritance, uikit, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have inherited UIGestureRecognizer as mentioned [in apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2)
But here it detects only upAndDown swipe i want to detect leftAndRight swipe also(like a ticle) with the same class and i know how to detect it but don't know how to invoke different selectos for different actions 
I mean like in UISwipeGestureRecognizer do for left and right swipes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the gesture recognizer object's direction property.

Comment: Can you explain how to use it or give an example